# I'm unable to run server due to this error: 'urls.py'>' does not appear to have any pattern'"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Error:

> raise `ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))`
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'dtapp.urls' from '`D:\\pylearn\\dt\\dtapp\\urls.py'>p.urls`' from `D:\\pylearn\\dt\\dtapp\\` then the issue is probably caused by a circterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

**urls.py**

```
  from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.news),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def news(request):
    return HttpResponse ("n iuri u iou")
```

**urls.py(django)**

```
  from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import url,include

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^dtapp/', include('dtapp.urls'))

    ]
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: in your new file urls.py for any app , you should add line app_name="nameoftheapp"